# HTTP POST using web service

Tags: c#, xml, asmx

I have been doing some Google searches and only getting partial successful on this topic. I was wondering if someone could suggest an example of doing an HTTP POST using C# to send XML to HTTP service.

I have a asmx web service that extracts data from database and I save that data to XML document. Now I have to send that XML document using SOAP protocol to HTTP service.

I have this part of code for connectig to service

```
WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create("https://WEB_URL");
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new CertificatePolicyClass();

                string username = "SOMETHING";
                string password = "ELSE";
                string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;
                CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
                mycache.Add(new Uri("https://WEB_URL"), "Basic", new  NetworkCredential(username, password));
                myReq.Credentials = mycache;
                myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

                WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
                Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

So does anybody have a code to send XML document to http service, this part I don't know how to write, I don't know am I on the write trace, I belive it has to go somethig like this

```
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

So plese can somebody help me! THANKS!

Comment: other stuff are involved, the asmx is current company standard..

Comment: using `XmlSerializer` or `XDocument`, you can write your xml string(SOAP) to `myReq.GetRequestStream()`.

Comment: OK... that was the expected answer, but better ask anyway. I am certainly not the guy you need, but I think I remeber using this quite a long time ago, and Visual Studio auto generated a client for the service (a reference it was call if I remember correctly), then I just had to call the code. Is it no longer working like this?

Comment: I already done the serializing, and on the end i have serialized XML document but I don't know how to make HTTP POST to another service, this part of the code I don't know hoe to write...

Comment: It works if you have asmx on the other side, but on the other side is http service,and you have to write "the sending part"

Comment: OK, didn't know that... thx for your clarification (am learning more than helping here, sorry)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is something I get, hope it's useful to you:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://WEB_URL");
myReq.Method = "POST";
myReq.ContentType = "text/xml";
myReq.Timeout = 30000;
myReq.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", ":\"#save\"");

byte[] PostData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocument);
myReq.ContentLength = PostData.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = myReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(PostData, 0, PostData.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Ok, this is good, I have to try it, where can I put my XML doc in this code?

Comment: byte[] PostData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocument);

Comment: I have this code: xmlObject = SerializeAnObject(Agr3PL); and then this xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlObject); when i write byte[] PostData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc); it gives me an error but with this byte[] PostData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlObject); it OK?? xmlDoc is an xml document and xmlObject is a serialized result, i don't know if it's ok to to this way?

Comment: Here xmlDocument is a string. it's the xml content.

Comment: then it's ok, xmlObject is a string, filled with a result from database, ok thank's very much!! You helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    string soap = 
    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
       xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
       xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
      <soap:Body>
        <Register xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
          <id>123</id>
          <data1>string</data1>
        </Register>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>";


HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/WebServices/CustomerWebService.asmx");
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction"http://tempuri.org/Register\"");
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
req.Accept = "text/xml";
req.Method = "POST";

using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
{
     using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
     {
          stmw.Write(soap);
     }
}

WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```