# how to pass JSON string as input parameter WCF RESTful service?

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, poster

I have a web service as below,

```
  [ServiceContract]
        public interface IRestServiceImpl
        {             
            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                UriTemplate = "json/{jsondata}")]
            void JSONData(string jsondata);       
        }


    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        List<ClsTripAdvisorData> lst = new List<ClsTripAdvisorData>();
        ClsTripAdvisorData _ClsTripAdvisorData = null;

        #region IRestServiceImpl Members       
        public void JSONData(string jsondata)
        {
            string[] data = jsondata.Split('&');
        }
}
```

Its expecting a JSON input. while i am testing this service with poster by passing a JSON string as  query string request  as below,

```
http://localhost:1162/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/api_version=4 &hotels=[{"ta_id":97497,"partner_id":"229547","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547"},{"ta_id":97832,"partner_id":"id34234","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234"}] &start_date=2013-07-01 &end_date=2013-07-03 &num_adults=2 &num_rooms=1 &lang=en_US &currency=USD &user_country=US &device_type=d &query_key=6167a22d1f87d2028bf60a8e5e27afa7_191_1360299600000_2_2
```

Here my string parameter is `api_version=4 &hotels=[{"ta_id":97497,"partner_id":"229547","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547"},{"ta_id":97832,"partner_id":"id34234","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234"}] &start_date=2013-07-01 &end_date=2013-07-03 &num_adults=2 &num_rooms=1 &lang=en_US &currency=USD &user_country=US &device_type=d &query_key=6167a22d1f87d2028bf60a8e5e27afa7_191_1360299600000_2_2`

Its not hitting the service method break point while debugging.

At the same time its working for the following JSON as below,

```
http://localhost:1162/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/asd
```

The service method not taking the JSON string input,

I just want send this string as body part of my web service.But i dont know how to send and receive this json string using wcf rest service

Comment: Since the Method is POST it should get the JSON as content of the call rather that as part of the URL (which would be the right thing to do if you were using GET)

Comment: @simpleBob:sorry to say but i did't get what you are saying....if possible than give me some example

Comment: The method to call a WS with parameters as part of the URL, for example `www.myWsURL.com?var1="wohoo"&var2="meh"` is called GET. When you set `Method = "POST"`you are supposed to attach the data to the body of the call (see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451086/386738))

Comment: @simpleBob:okey...thanks but i am using poster for sending data and when i attach my data to body it will give me error like "Endpoint not found. Please see the help page"

Answer (score 1):

Add the following decoration to your method

```
<OperationContract()> _
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="YourCoolFunction?inpt={inpt}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml)> _
    Public Function YourCoolFunction(inpt As String) As String
```

In the .svc file, add
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"

In web.config add

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="YourFile.svc"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Comment: but this is get method and i want post method ......actully i have json string and i want post this string in to my service using rest web service...i search in google in found i have to send this data in to body part but how i dont know

Comment: Like this(?): http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/fetching-request-body-rest-json-output-75574.aspx

Comment: yes some what like this...and i tried this code but when i send data to my service it ll give error like The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: :yes this method working for given json but its not working on my string ......my string is api_version=4
&hotels=[{"ta_id":97497,"partner_id":"229547","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547"},{"ta_id":97832,"partner_id":"id34234","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234"}]
&start_date=2013-07-01
&end_date=2013-07-03
&num_adults=2
&num_rooms=1
&lang=en_US
&currency=USD
&user_country=US
&device_type=d
&query_key=6167a22d1f87d2028bf60a8e5e27afa7_191_1360299600000_2_2